# Pre-Load pages on xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I was searching for tricks to make my Xamarin Forms app faster, and I came across this [article](https://newbedev.com/slow-startup-of-xamarin-app). Well, I have tried out some options there but I am finding it difficult to achieve the last option that says;

- **Pre-Load screens:** This improved by a lot the performance on the app
  itself what we did is load on each screen, on background, the views
  and view-models that where needed next, so when pushing them onto the
  navigation stack they were already loaded. This reduced by a lot the
  time on transition between pages.

This seems to me as a good option and what I have done is to insert pages I maybe needing next onto the Stack before navigating to the page like so; however, I don't know if I am doing this the right way.

```
    public ProductHomePageViewModel()
    {
        Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.InsertPageBefore(new TilePage(), Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.NavigationStack[0]);
    }
```

But this doesn't work well when it is done on a homepage where a click of a back button should exit the app. But in this case clicking the back button navigates to the next page on the stack.

Please assist me on how to pre-load pages. Any advice is good. Thank you!

Comment: It's true that the code that you pasted will not work. Using `InsertPageBefore` just changes the navigation stack and does what you say, when you press the backbutton, it goes to the "previous" page. One way of achieve what you want might be creating the instances of the pages in the background and keep it in memory. And then just push the page that was created

Comment: Your idea is worth more than a million dollar @Juan Sturla. Please how do I do this, Any sample codes will go far in helping me. I have never tried this.

Comment: Usually we use `Navigation.PushAsync(new MyPage())` . But we can split this into 2 steps: `MyPage pageVar= new Page();` and in another step do `Navigation.PushAsync(pageVar)` That pageVar can be anywhere in your code. You can even implement something like a [Singleton](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8911c4/singleton-design-pattern-in-C-Sharp/)

Comment: Just be aware of when you create your MyPage instance, because the constructor of MyPage will only be run once

Answer (score 0):

Like I said in the comments, you could use some kind of Singleton Pattern, but for pages.

I'll pust an example. Consider the following code

```
public partial class Page1 : ContentPage
    {
        private static Page1 _myinstance;
        public static Page1 myinstance
        {
            get
            {
                Prepare();
                return _myinstance;
            }
        }

    public static void Prepare()
    {
        if (_myinstance == null)
        {
            _myinstance = new Page1();
        }
    }

    public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

For any other Page, you could call `Navigation.PushAsync(Page1.Instance)` . If Page1 was instanced, it will not run the constructor again, just the first time Instance is called.

But if you want to "Prepare" it beforehand, you could call in a background method the `Page1.Prepare()`

Remember, the constructor will be executed only once. So the page will be like "Cached"

Comment: Thank you so much for this exposure. However, Singleton most times have parameterless single constructor. And this typically makes it hard to pass in paramters maybe when a user clicks on a button or a listview to navigate to a detail page or something

Comment: Yes, you might expose another method to do that configuration or passing parameters. It might get a little messy

Comment: Yes very messy and super hard to unit test the whole thing if need be. However, you have really exposed me to a great concept here. Thank you @Juan Sturla